# Are the diffusion terms conservative?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, diffusion, navier-stokes, conservative-field

Generally the [diffusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion) terms are of the form $$D =   \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\mu \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right)  .$$

Is this this term conservative or nonconservative?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of fluid dynamics, a *conservation law* is one in which the net flux in is equal to the net flux out. This is typically represented as the PDE,<sup>1</sup>
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot\mathbf F=S\tag{1}
$$
where $u$ is the conserved quantity, $\mathbf F$ the flux and $S$ the source term.<sup>2</sup> In your case, $\mathbf F=-\mu\nabla u$, so it is a conservative term because it satisfies (1).

Note, though, that the domain of dependence for a diffusion equation at a point  $\left(\mathbf x,\,t\right)$ is the entire domain at all previous times. This differs from the convective equation where the domain of dependence is along characteristics (lines that satisfy $du/dt=0$).

<sup>1. This can be equivalently written as an integral equation.</sup>
<sup>2. Often times $S=0$.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This form is conservative in the sense that, if you approximate the right hand side with a central finite difference approximation (using $\mu$ at the boundary of each grid cell and u at the center of each cell), the finite difference approximation will automatically conserve mass.

For those of us who solve diffusive problems using numerical methods, this is what a conservative form of the diffusion terms represents. An example of the non-conservative form would be if we differentiated by the product rule to obtain the mathematically equivalent form:  $$D=\mu\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial t^2}+\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial x}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$If this were expressed in finite difference form, the finite difference scheme would not automatically conserve mass. Such a version would be regarded as non-conservative.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos and OP:  I received a down-vote for this, but I double down on what I said relative to the use of the term conservative in describing diffusional terms in numerical analysis.  I stake my reputation on it.

Comment: NB, that doesn't ping me unless I've commented first. Anyway, I disagree with your answer simply because it's numerically conservative only because it's *mathematically conservative.* OP nowhere mentions numerical methods, only mathematical & physical terms (cf. the tags), so I don't think this answer provides anything relevant.

Comment: I'm just talking about how we use the term in the numerical solution of diffusion problems.  This is my experience with the term, and this is what I interpreted that the OP was asking about.  Sorry if that doesn't coincide with your range of experience.

Comment: I understand that, but note that numerical methods are derived from mathematical formalisms (i.e., FD is an approximation of a derivative). So saying it is numerical is approximately equivalent (but IMO inferior) to mathematical.

Comment: I don't know what this all means.  We haven't heard back from the OP yet, so we don't really know precisely what he meant.  I was simply interpreting his question from my experience base, and you were interpreting it from your experience base.  I realize he didn't mention solving a finite difference form of the diffusion equation that automatically conserves mass, but it wouldn't be the first time that a member didn't precisely articulate what he was asking.  I can't see how you can be so certain that your interpretation of his question is what he really meant (ruling out all other possibles.